# Custom Template in ArcGIS Online - Print Service Failing

Tags: arcgis-online, printing, template

I am trying to create a print service in a web experience building using ArcGIS Online that uses a custom layout template. I have followed the tutorial on the below video but come into a problem. When connected to my enterprise portal I can share the "Export Web map" tool as a Web Tool but when I am connected to AGOL it is greyed out. Is it possible to share these as a Web Tool in AGOL or only possible in Enterprise?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUHg7rgTRn4

Or does anyone know how to set up a custom print template on AGOL?